# Remote sensing and GIS

Tags: remote-sensing

Please how can I get landcover landuse data from landsat 4 or landsat 5.

Please can anyone help me and provide me the details?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I suspect there are a few assumptions implicit in your post. Could you please confirm that you are interested in historical landcover/landuse data from the periods when Landsat 4 and 5 were operational? Probably you want time series, right? Are you interested in a specific region? You want to do it automatically or a tutorial for manual classification? Also the title of your post is too broad.